# Need to override Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized.php

Tags: magento2

How to override this below file?
Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized.php

I need to override protected function inside this file, I tried with reference but not working

I have add override using plugin method but it is not working please advise if I am wrong:

In etc/di.xml add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized">
    <plugin name="cmarix-pepperjam-itemized-model" type="[VendorName][ModuleName]\Plugin\ItemizedPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
 </config>
```

And In [VendorName][ModuleName]\Plugin\ItemizedPlugin.php file add below code

```
<?php

namespace [VendorName][ModuleName]\Plugin;

class ItemizedPlugin
{    
    protected function aftergetQuantity($item)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/afterlog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        if ($item->getProduct()->canConfigure()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return (int) $item->getQtyOrdered();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

Comment: try with <preference in your di.xml

Comment: tried not working

Comment: Where is this file coming from? Is it a magento module?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Comment: You cannot override a protected/public function using Plugin or preference..Is this your custom module?

Comment: Pepperjam is 3rd party purchase module

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override the file as this following steps

Step 1: you need to create di.xml file in your own Module. Path: `[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\etc\`

Step 2: Write this following code in your di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Beacon\Itemized"/>
</config>
```

Comment: I have already override using same way but it is not override
I have created di.xml file in etc folder and added below code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Beacon\Itemized" />
</config>


After that I have created model file in below location:
[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\Beacon\Itemized.php

And added function that I want to override

Comment: okay, now you can try plugin after to override the method.

Comment: But I need to override protected method so it is not override using plugin

Comment: I have updated my question please chk & advice

Comment: Can you share Itemized.php code here (Pepperjam\Network\Model\Beacon\Itemized).